# R: plotting graphs (ggplot vs autoplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graph, data-visualization

I am following a R tutorial over here https://rviews.rstudio.com/2017/09/25/survival-analysis-with-r/

The computer I use for work does not have internet access nor a USB port - it only has R with some preinstalled libraries. The tutorial requires "survival", "ggplot2", "ranger", "dplyr" and "ggfortify". The computer I use for work has all of these libraries EXCEPT ggfortfiy. Apparently, a function called "autoplot" is required from the ggfortify library to make some of the plots in this tutorial.

When I try to run the code from the tutorial:

```
#load libraries
library(survival)
library(ranger)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

#load data
data(veteran)
head(veteran)

# Kaplan Meier Survival Curve
km <- with(veteran, Surv(time, status))
km_fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data=veteran)

#plot(km_fit, xlab="Days", main = 'Kaplan Meyer Plot') #base graphics is always ready


#here is where the error is 
autoplot(km_fit)
```

I get the following error: `Error: Objects of type survfit not supported by autoplot.`

Does anyone know how to fix this? Is it possible to make similar plots without the ggfortify library? Can it just be made with ggplot2?

On my personal computer, I am able to make this plot once I install the ggfortify library.

(note: I also do not have the "survminer" library)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, because the `autoplot` function uses `ggplot2` under the hood:

```
tibble(time = km_fit$time, surv = km_fit$surv, 
       min = km_fit$lower, max = km_fit$upper) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = time)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = surv)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = min, ymax = max), alpha = 0.3)
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you! Can you please explain how you came to this answer?

Comment: I tried to adapt your code for the next parts of the tutorial. In the next part, a graph is produced but it doesnt look the same way as the tutorial.



km_trt_fit <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ trt, data=veteran)





tibble(time = km_trt_fit$time, surv = km_trt_fit$surv, 
       min = km_trt_fit$lower, max = km_trt_fit$upper) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = time, group = factor(veteran$trt), colour = factor(veteran$trt), fill = factor(veteran$trt))) +
    geom_line(aes(y = surv)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = min, ymax = max), alpha = 0.3)

Comment: (here is a cleaner version : https://shrib.com/#Jordan-zj6Moa)

Comment: (there is a follow up post here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65042472/r-tibble-vs-ggplot2-plotting-graphs)